# Internet Explorer Table scroll

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, scroll

I am trying to create scrollable table-cell. It works perfect in Chrome, but in IE (10+) it does NOT.

[http://test2.makeitfirst.com/](http://test2.makeitfirst.com) - just add a random product by clicking on an item below and look for the "add to basket" (the basket should turn green) then click on green basket button and HERE IT IS! The table will appear! What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work as you want it if you add the *overflow:auto* attribute to **nav class sc-menu** or **div class basket**

(Found using the Dev tools in IE 10)